# How do I add randomly generated strings and integers to arrays while the code is running?

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

I'm trying to make a text-based business game, where you can hire and fire employees. Max there can be 5 employees, once strength is reached five, we may fire employees. I have written code to randomly generate details of a new applicant, but I am not able to save the hired employee. Can someone please guide?

```
package TestPackage;

import java.util.*;

public class EmployeeRandomizer {
    /*this is where the employee's profile will be created and chosen by user. */

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        int spacesAvailable = 5;
        int employeesHired = 0;
        while(true) {
            Random generate = new Random();
            String[] name = {"John", "Marcus", "Susan", "Henry"};
            int[] age = {20,21,22,23,24,25,25,26,26,27,28,29,30,20,21,22,23,24,25,25,26,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50};
            String[] education = {"business", "accountant", "human resources","none"};
            for(int i = 0; i < employeesHired; i++){
                int index = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
                System.out.println(name[index]+age[index]+education[index]);
            }
            System.out.println("name: " +name[generate.nextInt(4)]);
            System.out.println("age: "+age[generate.nextInt(40)]);
            System.out.println("education: " +education[generate.nextInt(4)]);
            System.out.println("will you hire this person? (y/n)");
            Scanner hire = new Scanner(System.in);
            String hireEmployee = hire.next();
            if(hireEmployee.equals("y")) {
                System.out.println("you have hired a new employee!");
                spacesAvailable = spacesAvailable-1;
                employeesHired = employeesHired+1;
                System.out.println("employees: " + employeesHired);
                if(spacesAvailable>0 && employeesHired<5) {
                    System.out.println("There's " +spacesAvailable+" available spaces in your employee list.");
                    System.out.println("1. hire more employees");
                    System.out.println("2. view employees list");
                    Scanner hireMore = new Scanner(System.in);
                    String hireMoreAnswer =hireMore.next();
                    if (hireMoreAnswer.equals("1")) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (hireMoreAnswer.equals("2")) {
                        for(int i = 0; i < employeesHired;){
                            int index = (int)(Math.random() * 10);
                            System.out.println(name[index]);
                            System.out.println(age[index]);
                            System.out.println(education[index]);
                            break;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(spacesAvailable==0 || employeesHired==5) {
                    System.out.println("You have no more spaces left to hire more employees. (1 or 2?)");
                    System.out.println("1. Fire an employee (+1 space)");
                    System.out.println("2. Exit (more coming soon!)");
                    Scanner oneTwo = new Scanner(System.in);
                    String oneOrTwo = oneTwo.next();
                    if(oneOrTwo.equals("1")) {


                    }
                    if (oneOrTwo.contentEquals("2")) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(hireEmployee.equals("n")) {
                System.out.println("you have declined this application");
                System.out.println("There's " +spacesAvailable+" available spaces in your employee list. Would you like to hire more employees? (y/n)");
                Scanner hireMoreTwo = new Scanner(System.in);
                String hireMoreAnswerTwo =hireMoreTwo.next();
                if (hireMoreAnswerTwo.equals("y")) {
                    continue;
                }

                if (hireMoreAnswerTwo.equals("n")) {
                    break;
                }
            }

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a `break` in most of your `if` statements?  You even have it in one of your `for` loops, so it is basically not a loop anymore because it will just break out immediately every time.  Additionally you do not need to declare a `new Scanner(System.in)` every time you take input, just use the same one you already declared earlier.  Finally you should look into using `ArrayList` in order to store information such as the application you speak of.  Ideally you would make a custom class named `Application` or something along those lines, and create an `ArrayList<Application>`.

Comment: To what arrays would you like to add these randomly generated strings and integers?  I see no arrays sitting empty, ready and waiting to be filled with hired employees' data.

Comment: I've coded java since the initial beta version, and I've never used a break or continue. And I don't see a good reason for them here.

Comment: I used a break, and continue temporarily. I wasn't finished with the project since the hiring and firing was only one part of it.